# How to setup 802.11n wireless card in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have installed ubuntu 9.10 on my laptop. It has a 802.11n wireless card.
When I boot up to ubuntu, the wireless does not work. And if I connect to a wire network within ubuntu, it works.

Ubuntu can't detect any of the Wifi network in my home (other laptop can). And I click 'Enable Wireless' in the notification area, it said 'Device not found' for the Wireless Network.

The card is 'Intel Wireless-N Card with Bluetooth'

Can you please tell me how can I setup my wireless card in ubuntu 9.10?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is the card not recognized? Are you unable to connect to a AP (what type of encryption)?

Comment: Any particular wireless card?

Comment: Is the wireless card enabled in BIOS?

Comment: yes. it works under window7

Comment: Have you installed the drivers for the card.  I am going to guess there isn't any or if there is support its ver limited for a Linux driver provided by Intel.

Comment: Have you installed these packages, edited their config files from the command line and then recompiled your kernel? If not, you probably should. Year of Linux on the desktop, I say.

Comment: Why are you using 9.10?  I think hardware support would be better in the newer versions....

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problems, look for the specific card you are using with this command:

```
lspci
```

And Google for the driver of your specific card. I didn't have any trouble finding mine.